# not able to update image from data grid view in vb.net windows form application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view in vb.net windows application,i am populating grid view like this:
i wrote code in load evant like this

```
 Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as Phone,d.dtEmail as Email,d.empimage from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId order by cid", con.connect)

        dt1 = New DataTable
        bSource = New BindingSource
        adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
        bSource.DataSource = dt1
        gv.DataSource = bSource
        gv.Columns("cid").Visible = False
        gv.Columns("dtId").Visible = False
        Dim img As New DataGridViewImageColumn
        img.HeaderText = "Image"
        gv.Columns.Insert(6, img)

        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
            gv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = gv.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
        Next
        gv.Columns("empimage").Visible = False
```

in update button i wrote code like this:

```
Dim cid As Integer
        Dim dtid As Integer
        Dim cmpname As String
        Dim dtname As String
        Dim dtPhone As String
        Dim dtEmail As String
        Dim dtimage As Image


        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
            ' Dim rv = DirectCast(bSource.Current, DataRowView)
            Dim rv = DirectCast(gv.Rows(i).DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
            cid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Cid")

            dtid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("dtId")
            cmpname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")
            dtname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Department")
            dtPhone = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Phone")
            dtEmail = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Email")

            Using ms As New MemoryStream(rv.Row.Field(Of Byte())("empimage"))
                dtimage = New Bitmap(ms)
            End Using

            adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName", con.connect)
            adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("update DepartmentMaster_tbl set dtName = @dtName,dtPhone = @dtPhone,dtEmail = @dtEmail,empimage=@dtimage  where dtId=@dtid", con.connect)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpname)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtId", dtid)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtName", dtname)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtimage", dtimage)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
```

while executing this i am getting error in this line :**adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()**
Error:`No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type`

what is wrong with my code
any help is very appreciable??

Comment: r u saving image in database or just path of image?

Comment: i am saving image in database

Comment: Did you try just showing the picture from the database in a picturebox right after the binary block is converted back to an image format?

Comment: i can able to show my image from data base to my data grid view..this code i written in the update button,,if i want to edit any images,,i will edit and i will click update button,,that time i am getting this error